# Count the number of selected options using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have over 53 similar `select` sections in my DOM and I need to count how many of a particular option have been selected by the user.

An example of my DOM would be something like this:

```
<select name="attendance" class="dd" id="20130101">
  <option>p</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>s</option>
</select>
<select name="attendance" class="dd" id="20130102">
  <option>p</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>s</option>
</select>
... x 51 more times!
```

What I would like to do is return the quantity (count) of options where the user has selected "a" for example. I have tried `$('.dd option:selected').length` however it returns the total count of all select sections (being 53).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dkK5x/

```
$(".dd option:selected[value=a]").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just combine selectors, in this case `:contains`:

```
$(".dd option:contains(a):selected").length;
```

However, this depends on no option being contained entirely by another option, for example:

```
<option>a</option>
<option>aa</option>
```

You could also set the `value` of the option instead, perhaps even with jQuery:

```
$("option").val(function () {
   return $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put a value-attribute into your options

```
<select name="attendance" class="dd" id="20130101">
  <option value="p">p</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="s">s</option>
</select>
```

Through this, the selector is fairly easy through using an attribute-selector:

```
$('select option[value="a"]:selected').length;
```

I created a small fiddle to show you this in actual use: http://jsfiddle.net/mx5Yd/1/

The number of selected options with the "a" - value is logged to the console when clicking "count"